# Unable to make connection between mysql 8.0.18 with eclipse 2019-09

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

I have mysql8.0.18 installed on machine and eclipse 2019-09 but unable to make connection between them, It run the first page but unable to make connection with database.

```
HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error
```

Comment: A code snippet and full error log would help. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Internal server error means that something went wrong in the backend code, but does not tell us what. It may not even be related to mysql. Check out your webserver's logs if those contain more information or even better, debug your code and identify the actual error. Based on the actual error, pls try to rectify it yourself first. If you cannot, only then come back here and share the error and the code that causes it with us!

Answer (score -2):

maybe this post can help you man [post link](https://coderanch.com/t/688823/databases/Eclipse-connect-MySQL)
. To use mysql in eclipse, you should import connector: mysql-connector-java-5.1.45-bin.jar or some later version in the Eclipse web-inf lib.
Moreover, you should make your question clearer such as what kind of project u are working on, ... that much helps us to help in more detail